# Find all list items where a date property is in a specific interval

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I have a list of type "Time". I want to select entries from that list where the property "Day" are in a specific year and month.

```
public class Time
{
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    public string Opens { get; set; }
    public string Closes { get; set; }
}    

List<Time> GetTimes(int year, int month) 
{
     var list = new List<Time>();
     ...
}
```

How would I do this in an efficent way?

Regards,
David

Comment: Have you tried anything? Linq is the way

Comment: Yeah, I realize that linq is the way too, although when it has to do with a property inside a list it became problematic for me. I though that someone probably would have a fast solution.

Comment: "How would I do this in an efficent way?" you would not use linq :)

Comment: @MongZhu - that is a wrong statement. If it is an in memory colleciton - it is just like a foreach loop + getting the differed execution bonus (if not returning `List` but `IEnumerable`. Also, if it is from database - then very depends still on what specific query, but can be optimized a lot

Comment: @David - *an efficent way* - what is the collection size, is it in memory or DB and what is the times you are talking about.

Comment: Your problem really was that you didn't know how to check if a given `DateTime` has a specific year and month? Have you looked at the documentation of `DateTime` or used intellisense?

Comment: The collections isn't that big actually. It was more about not using nestled foreach's or something like that.

Comment: @David - then linq is for sure the way :) easy to write and understand is also under "efficient code"

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yeah, sorry. I somehow made it way more complicated than it was... As i said in another comment: Vacation-brain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use linq [`.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
return collection.Where(item => item.Day.Year == year && item.Day.Month == month).ToList();
```

*Consider changing the `Day` property name to `Date` - better reflects what it holds*

Comment: @David - also, unless you really want it as a list I'd recommend returning an `IEnumerable<Time>` instead of the list - you get the bonus of the differed execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply by linq:

```
return list.Where(date => date.Year == year && date.Month == month).ToList();
```